# child_process is not executing on ec2 nodejs server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have node server which is on an ec2 instance running Ubuntu.

I maintain code on Gitlab and push updates there.

The manual updating process is to simply pull the changes and restart the server which I want to automate and for that I am using Gitlab webhook and created a simple endpoint which executes:

```
 childProcess.exec('git pull && bash deploy.sh',{ cwd: '/home/ubuntu/someXyzFolder' }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
                if (err) {
                 return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                res.status(200).send("OK");
              });
```

So childProcess is not able to execute these commands as its sending 500 status with this error:

```
{"killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"git pull && bash deploy.sh"}
```

several people have suffered from this problem and solved it by creating a swap due to low memory

I ran `free` command on my server which replied back

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:/var/somefolder/somefolder$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1007532      404276      381512         772      221744      452944
Swap:             0           0           0
```

According to this, I should be having enough ram right?

I am not sure whether Linux oom is killing it or something else.

Do let me know your thoughts on it.

-Thanks

**EDIT:** here is my deploy.sh

```
git pull
npm install
gulp build
sudo killall forever
sudo killall node

rm /removeTheSymlinkOfTheCurrentBuildFolder
ln -s /makeaNewFolderWithCurrentTimeStamp/`ls -ltr /some  | tail -n 1 | awk {' print $9 '}` /andMakeItCurrent

sudo forever /currentBuildFolder/server.js &
```

Comment: proces ended with error and describe it on output. switch to `spawn` and print console stdout i stderr

Comment: What do the stdout and stderr say?

Comment: did not check them until not they throw:

 git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: when I do these manually git pull works like it should....

Comment: Can you post deploy.sh file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally fixed the issue.

The ssh was generated with when I logged in as the user ubuntu and then stored in Gitlab.

I was opening my 2nd server ( which would kill and restart my main server ) using `sudo` which was creating the issue.

Now everything seems to be working fine.